# C++ Find the most occurrence of a char using maps

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find the most occurrence of  char in a dat file. so if there are 24 e's in the file and 8 c's id like it to print out 'e'. I'm getting an error on the " * " of the int max var. The is the error:

Error   3   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::pair' to 'int'

```
ifstream infile(filename);
    if (!infile.is_open()) return;    
    char x;
    map<char, int> count;
    while (infile >> x) count[x]++;
    for (auto it : count)    
        cout << it.first << " " << it.second << endl;
    int max = *max_element(count.begin(), count.end(), count.value_comp());
    cout << max << endl;
    return ' ';
```

as always any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are there are only 256 chars, you could just use an array for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues

- count.value_comp() compares the keys of map::value_type(s), which are pairs
- max_element returns an iterator to a pair

You might change the code to:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("filename");
    if (!infile.is_open())
        return 1;    // Check if file opened correctly
    char x;
    typedef std::map<char, int> map_type;
    map_type count;
    while (infile >> x) count[x]++;
    for (auto it : count)    // Pull this out of the while loop
        std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second << std::endl;
    auto less_count = [] (const map_type::value_type& a, const map_type::value_type& b) {
        return a.second < b.second;
    };
    auto max_pair = std::max_element(count.begin(), count.end(), less_count);
    int  max = max_pair->second;
    std::cout << max << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The most frequent it now returning as a smiley face lol?

Answer (score 2):

`std::max_element` will return ForwardIterator which in your case will be `map<char,int>::iterator` pointing to `pair<char,int>`. You have to change the last line to

```
 int max = max_element(count.begin(), count.end(),count.value_comp())->second;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you dereference `std::map::iterator` you get `std::pair` and you try to assign it to `int`. Correct syntax would be:

```
int max = max_element(count.begin(), count.end(), count.value_comp())->second;
```

but you should check if there are elements in that map, otherwise you may dereference `count.end()` with UB. That would happen if file is empty for example.